# Serve single page app under specific path with AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, single-page-application

At the moment I have `mydomain.com` pointing to a Django EC2 instance with ABL in front of it and CF in front of the ABL.
Now I have the requirement of serving a React single page app under an specific path `mydomain.com/my-specific-path` (of course everything under HTTPS)

I tried everything I could to host my SPA in an S3 bucket and use CF to redirect the calls to that S3. But it was impossible to serve the app over HTTPS that way (because of S3 hosting and subfolders).

I am thinking now about setting a reverse proxy in front of my Django app. But I don't know if that is the best solution, and I don't know the best way to do it.

Could you please give me some insights about how to serve a SPA under a specific path?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1) Add your ALB as an origin to your CloudFront distribution

2) Add your S3 bucket **website URL** as an origin to your CloudFront distribution

**Note:** Adding S3 as an origin from the dropdown box that auto populates here will not work for hosting a website out of S3. This feature is for hosting static files only.

2a) Optionally lock your S3 bucket down to CloudFront using a condition in the bucket policy that checks for header value that only CloudFront and your S3 bucket knows

3) Set the default root object in your CloudFront distribution to be index.html

4) Upload your react app **to a sub-folder in your S3 bucket**, not in the root. This sub-folder must match the path you set on your React app origin in CloudFront

5) Set a default behaviour in your CloudFront distribution that points to your ALB

6) Set a behaviour in your CloudFront distribution that points `my-specific-path/*` to your S3 bucket origin

7) Terminate SSL on your CloudFront distribution using AWS Certificate Manager

This setup should give you SSL on both your Django app and your React app being hosted in S3.

I've got this running, screen shots below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: We couldn't serve our index.html file under https. Maybe we didn't `Terminate SSL on your CloudFront distribution using AWS Certificate Manager` ... Any documentation on that so I can double check?

Comment: Furthermore, we had to point CF to the S3 domain URL to be able to serve the file. Is this correct?

Comment: we got a timeout when serving over HTTPS by the way (if I remember well)

Comment: Yes, when you set up the S3 origin you can auto-select it from pre-populated values in CloudFront (it knows about your S3 buckets). The field is populated with the S3 bucket URL or similar. Have updated the answer with some docs on how to install SSL cert to CloudFront + how to serve S3 content over SSL with CloudFront.

Comment: Thank you, I think we already tried that. The problem was that we couldn't serve it when hitting the URL without the file name. So `https://example.com/my-specific-path/index.html` but `https://example.com/my-specific-path/` just downloads a zero-bytes file (the request is set to `content-type: application/x-directory`) and `https://example.com/my-specific-path` gives an error (the request is set to `content-type: application/xml`). Any idea??

Comment: And then is when we finished in here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-default-directory-indexes-in-amazon-s3-backed-amazon-cloudfront-origins-using-lambdaedge/ which will force the URL to include index.html

Comment: I've updated my answer - apologies, some of my original was incorrect. I have this running myself now, so have put screen shots into the answer as well. The main difference is using the S3 website URL as opposed to choosing the auto-populated S3 endpoint in the origin set up. Choosing this would result in an XML 403 response. Additionally, the sub-directory in the S3 bucket + path in the CF origin are important as well.

Comment: Thank you again. I'll try it again, even though I am 99% sure we already tried this config. Did you access through HTTPS the first time? With a fresh cache? If we do that config and invalidate the cache after a new deployment on S3, we cannot access on HTTPS, we have to access on HTTP and once it is cache, we can access on HTTPS ... 

Comment: This works both redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS and with HTTPS directly on the first try after invalidating the cache.

Comment: Done! Thanks very much mate!